# Detect NPC nested model changes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inotifypropertychanged, postsharp

I have hierarchy of NPC classes (implemented by PostSharp)

```
[NotifyPropertyChanged]
class A
{
}
[NotifyPropertyChanged]
class B
{
   [Child]
   public AdvisableCollection<A> Childs { get;set; }
}
[NotifyPropertyChanged]
class C
{
   [Child]
   public A PropertyA { get; set; }
   [Child]
   public B PropertyB { get; set; }
}
```

How can I subscribe to object of C class to detect if any property of any nested object is changed (including changes to Childs collection)? I need to get notification when my model becomes dirty

Answer (score 0):

Looking at http://doc.postsharp.net/aggregatable-adding or http://doc.postsharp.net/advisable-collections I would say, you're missing the `[Aggregatable]`-Attributes on your classes..

Comment: Its better to quote the most relevant part of your link than post the link only in case the target site is unreachable or goes offline.